# Get the two first and last chars of a string C#

Tags: c#, .net

Well I'd like to get the two first and last chars of a string. This is what I already got

```
public static string FirstLastChars(this string str)
{
    return str.Substring(0,2);
}
```

BTW. It's an extension method

Comment: What if the string has less than 4 characters ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting C# 8.0 you can use array ranges:

```
public static class StringExtentions {
    public static string FirstLastChars(this string str)
    {
       // If it's less that 4, return the entire string
       if(str.Length < 4) return str;
       return str[..2] + str[^2..];
    }
}
```

Check solution here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/zBBT3U

Comment: Note that this requires C#8 *and*  .Net Core - if you're using C# 8 with .Net Framework, you can't use array ranges.

Comment: `str[..]` => this doesn't really achieve anything.

Comment: Just showcasing the indexes. I removed it and now return only the original string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the existing string Substring method. Check the following code.

```
public static string FirstLastChars(this string str)
{
    if(str.Length < 4)
    {
      return str;
    }
    return str.Substring(0,2) + str.Substring(str.Length - 1, 1) ;
}
```

Comment: Why is Not str.Substring(0,1) ?

Comment: cause in the question user asked for "two first characters" not the first character only.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can make use of the `Span` Api.

First you need to create a buffer and pass that to a `Span` instance. (With this you have a writable `Span`.)

```cs
var strBuffer = new char[3];
var resultSpan = new Span<char>(strBuffer);
```

From the original `str` you can create two `ReadOnlySpan<char>` instances to have references for the first two letters and for the last letter.

```cs
var strBegin = str.AsSpan(0, 2);
var strEnd = str.AsSpan(str.Length - 1, 1);
```

In order to make a single string from two `Span` objects you need to concatenate them. You can do this by making use of the writable span.

```cs
strBegin.CopyTo(resultSpan.Slice(0, 2));
strEnd.CopyTo(resultSpan.Slice(2, 1));
```

Finally let's convert the `Span<char>` into `string`. You can do this in several ways, but the two most convenient commands are the followings:

- `new string(resultSpan)`
- `resultSpan.ToString()`

---

Helper:

```cs
public static class StringExtentions
{
    public static string FirstLastChars(this string str)
    {
        if (str.Length < 4) return str;

        var strBuffer = new char[3];
        var resultSpan = new Span<char>(strBuffer);

        var strBegin = str.AsSpan(0, 2);
        var strEnd = str.AsSpan(str.Length - 1, 1);

        strBegin.CopyTo(resultSpan.Slice(0, 2));
        strEnd.CopyTo(resultSpan.Slice(2, 1));

        return new string(resultSpan);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string str = "Hello World!";
        Console.WriteLine(str.FirstLastChars()); //He!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code-

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] numbers = { 12, 34, 64, 98, 32, 46 };
        var finalList = numbers.Skip(2).SkipLast(2).ToArray();

        foreach(var item in finalList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item + "");
        }
    }
```